# How to find values between two radii in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has columns named Longitude, Latitude, and Value. It looks like this:

```
Time                 Longitude      Latitude    SSHA
11/22/2013 8:57     -123.603607     81.377536   0.348
11/22/2013 8:57     -124.017502     81.387791   0.386
11/22/2013 8:57     -124.432344     81.397611   0.383
11/22/2013 8:57     -124.848099     81.406995   0.405
11/22/2013 8:57     -125.264724     81.415942   --
...                  ...            ...         ...
```

I am interested in finding values that lie between 0.5 and 0.25 longitude/latitude of the point (-71, 40). Here is my current code that results in an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import math
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\pathexample\\documents\\folder1\\csvfile.csv")
df1 = df[((df[['Longitude','Latitude']] - [-71, 40])**2).sum(axis=1) < 0.5**2]
df2 = df[((df[['Longitude','Latitude']] - [-71, 40])**2).sum(axis=1) < 0.25**2]
df[~(df1|df2)].to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\pathexample\\documents\\folder1\\csvfile.csv")
```

I am using the Pythagorean theorem to retain rows of the csv file that lies within 0.5 lon/lat of the point of interest and deleting all other rows with the code 
`df1 = df[((df[['Longitude','Latitude']] - [-71, 40])**2).sum(axis=1) < 0.5**2]`. 
For example, the code below would take the csv file and remove any rows that is not within 0.5 lon/lat of the point (-71,40).

```
df = pd.read_csv((r"C:\\Users\\pathexample\\documents\\folder1\\csvfile.csv")
df = df[((df[['Longitude','Latitude']] - [-71, 40])**2).sum(axis=1) < 0.5**2]
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\pathexample\\documents\\folder1\\csvfile.csv")
```

The above mentioned code works and I am trying to combine two versions of this code and getting values between 0.5 and 0.25 lon/lat of the point of interest using `df[~(df1|df2)].to_csv()`. However, this part does not work as intended. I get the error, "unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'". How would I modify this?

Comment: Hello Bob, is it possible for you to post some sample input and an example of the data that you expect as the output ?

Comment: I updated my question. The table I have has numerous values with different longitude/latitude. But I am interested in find the rows whose lon/lat is between ±0.5 and ±0.25 of the point (-71,40). So, a value whose lon/lat with (-71.1,40) should be deleted.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your logic, but looks like you are trying to list values that do not belong to union of df1 and df2. This logic is wrong and anyway the syntax is wrong in terms of pandas. To get dataframe of values "in betweem", try this:

```
df[df.isin(df1) & ~df.isin(df2)].dropna()
```